# How to change Readme png size

Tags: html, markdown, png, readme

I use the following to use picture inside the readme,
It works however the picture size is small, can I control it somehow ?

```
![alt text](img/trk.png)
```

I try as suggested here

But it doesnt work, I dont see the picture.
Should I change the image type from png? something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all flavors of Markdown support setting height and width of images. To be safe, Markdown supports HTML too, so instead you can use:

```
<img src="img/trk.png" alt="alt text" width="200" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I try it but It doesnt work, do I miss something?

Comment: should I change the format of the picture from png?